# Asp.net uncommon diagram drawing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, .net

Problem is that i cannot use js libs etc because diagram should looks ***exactly*** like on the picture, but libs doesn't allow to customize enough their view

[image]

So easiest way is just draw an image in code behind and paste it, but I'm thinking about perfomance etc, so I'd like to draw it using css and html. I found that i can use divs and set background, but I need linear gradient fill of diag columns. Please, advice.

Comment: [CSS gradient creator](http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html)

Comment: @NicholasV. it's fine, but 2 problems: in my case I have 3 gradient points - blue-white-blue, I don't care about it, but second problem is really important: It should work in any browser lvl IE9+, but markup differs for every browser.

Comment: http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/ or http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ allows you to add more gradients so you should be able to do bwb